# Should I use `stringify!` for non-Rust source code strings like SQL queries?

Tags: sql, rust

TL;DR Does Rust provide specific stability guarantees about the behaviour of its lexer, specifically in regards to how it lexes non-Rust source code?

For context:

It occurred to me that this is possible:

```
let query = stringify!(
    CREATE TABLE table (
        row TEXT NOT NULL,
        another_row TEXT NOT NULL,
    );
);
```

`query` will now be a `&'static str` that contains a SQL query ready for use with whatever SQL library is in use. This can be a drop-in replacement for any embedded queries in your code. Obviously there are some problems and then there is the question of why, but those are besides the point.

Can the Rust lexer be relied upon to not break this code in a future update?

Comment: Awww. I disagree; I asked a specific question and then considered possible responses. At the least, the question about lexer stability is an extremely technical and specific one. And there is precedent for style and readability questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: *"Does that mean you should?"* - is not a specific question and the only one I see. Even if you are unsure with your own conclusions, this seems to lend itself more as a discussion rather than a practical answerable question. Style and readability questions are often closed as opinion-based.

Comment: I've modified the question to be less verbose and more specific, as well as removed my analysis. I hope that suits the medium of StackOverflow better.

Comment: How is this any better than using a `const QUERY : &'static str = "..."`?

Comment: I understand there are plenty of reasons not to do this. I'm simply wondering if Rust provides any specific stability guarantees about the behaviour of its lexer, specifically in regards to how it lexes non-Rust source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not recommend using `stringify!` for non-Rust code.

A macro gets its input tokens after lexing which means whitespace is mostly stripped (except for symbols where its [spacing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.Punct.html#method.spacing) indicates whether it was next to another symbol). Besides that, the rest of the source is available so you can create almost any DSL.

The problem with using `stringify!` though, is that it doesn't necessarily generate a string that respects your DSL's understanding of symbols based on the tokens given to it. In particular, the current implementation seems to generate Rust-like spacing. So non-Rust combinations of symbols that are meaningful in other languages may get split apart.

Examples:

```rust
fn main() {
    let sql_statement = stringify!(SELECT [1,2] @> [3,4]);
    dbg!(sql_statement);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:3] sql_statement = "SELECT [1, 2] @ > [3, 4]"
```

<sup>which is an invalid Postgres operator `@>`</sup>

```rust
fn main() {
    let python_code = stringify!(1 ** 2);
    dbg!(python_code);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:3] python_code = "1 * * 2"
```

<sup>which is an invalid Python exponentiation operator `**`</sup>

In addition, the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify.html) says:

> Note that the expanded results of the input tokens may change in the future. You should be careful if you rely on the output.

Comment: I have a dilemma: I am very grateful to your response, since as originally worded, this response has answered my question, and I am tempted to mark the response as the solution. However, the question has since changed, and I don't know if it can still be considered an answer to the question as it is currently worded. If it wasn't obvious already, I am very inexperienced with asking questions on StackOverflow and the appropriate etiquette.

Comment: @Kilo you're fine, but doesn't this still answer the question? Even if you're asking about the lexing properties of Rust, your goal is clearly to use `stringify` for SQL queries which I answer is unsuitable so the lexing property part is a bit moot, no?

Comment: Ok, I see the point of the updated question now. I'll see if I can revise my answer or maybe someone else can make a better answer.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm kinda overwhelmed by all of this.

Comment: @Kilo You're doing great. Keep posting questions (and answers) and you'll get the hang of it before you know it.

Comment: @Kilo I have revised my answer, hopefully it better addresses your question now.